# Selecting a webpage radio-button

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to do some webpage data extraction using VBA within excel.  I have managed to automate the login process, which takes me to a new page with a search form.  This form has an input field for 'Search Value' and a series of radio buttons that specify the variable to conduct the search on eg. ID number, Name.  I am trying to automate filling in the input field and selecting one of the radio buttons and then submitting the form.

The code I used to login does not seem to work on the next page where I need to do the search.  This is the HTML from the search page containing the input field:

```
 <table width="100%">
                        <tr>
                          <td style="font-weight: bold; width:10%;" nowrap="nowrap">Search Value</td>
                          <td style="width: 15%; text-align: left;">
                            <input name="txtSearch" type="text" id="txtSearch" onkeyup="return txtSearch_onkeyup()" style="background-color:White;border-color:#222244;border-width:1px;border-style:Solid;height:20px;width:125px;" />
```

Which I try to fill in using:

```
ieDoc.Document.getElementsByName("txtSearch")(0).Value = "Test String"
```

Or:

```
 ieDoc.Document.all.txtSearch.Value =  "Test String"
```

Or

```
ieDoc.Document.getElementByID("txtSearch").Value = "Test String"
```

...all giving me the same Object defined error.

I have confirmed that the ieDoc is referencing the correct page after the login (by checking the title in the immediate window), and tried to ensure it is not a timing issue with page-loading.

I know the HTML methods in vba tend to be temperamental but I've run out of ideas.  Any other way to access the input field on this page?

Comment: What's `ieDoc`?

Comment: It's the internet explorer object I create earlier with:

Comment: Set ieDoc = New InternetExplorerMedium

Comment: I've just realised that the page I'm working with has 2 frames.  Now trying to figure out how to access the frame in question

Answer (score 1):

Success!

I was trying to reference an element on a sub-frame within the IE object, which I accessed with:

```
ieDoc.Document.frames(0).Document.all.txtSearch.Value = "Hello!"
```